# Select with custom icon in SAPUI5

Tags: select, combobox, icons, sapui5, dropdown

Is posible make a select that shows a custom icon? or we only can use SAP icons?

I'm trying this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Lux.png)

I want a dropdown like this and next to the name country that we can see the flag of each country. Is posible for a dropdown?

this is the view:

```
<m:Label/>
<m:Select items="{ path: 'listcountries>/countrySet' }">
        <c:ListItem key="{listcountries>Land}" text="{listcountries>Landx}" icon="images/{Land}.png"/>
</m:Select>
```

{Land} is the same value that the name of the each picture.

and this the route of the pictures:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBwo0.png)

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with sap.m.Select. Here is a sample https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.Select/sample/sap.m.sample.SelectWithIcons

```xml
<Select>
    <core:ListItem key="item1" text="Text 1" icon="./path/to/icon1"/>
    <core:ListItem key="item2" text="Text 2" icon="./path/to/icon2"/>
</Select>
```

Here is a live example https://codepen.io/pdimov/pen/gORgdBm

Comment: Hi! but this is only works with SAP Icons. I mean, I want custom icons that I have in a folder in the project. But it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Can you post your code? Perhaps you are referencing a wrong URL, because all kinds of images are supported. Also the sizing of the image should be correct to look nice.

Comment: Perhaps the path to your images is wrong, take a look at the requests made in the Network tab. I have updated the answer with example.